# What is the converse of this result?

Tags: real-analysis, logic

Assume that:

1) $g$ is a real analytic function and has infinitely many real zeros.

2) $g$ assumes arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values, i.e., for all $K>0$, there are $s₁,s₂$ with $g(s₁)<-K$ and $g(s₂)>K$.

Then the fiber $g⁻¹(w)$ is infinite for all $w∈ℝ$.

My **question** is: What is the  converse of this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) $g$ is a real analytic function and has infinitely many real zeros.
>
> (2) $g$ assumes arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values, i.e., for all $K>0$, there are $s₁,s₂$ with $g(s₁)<-K$ and $g(s₂)>K$.
>
> (3)Then the fiber $g⁻¹(w)$ is infinite for all $w∈ℝ$.

This statement is of the form $((1)\land (2))\implies (3)$, thus

the converse is $(3)\implies \color{blue}((1) \land (2)\color{blue})$.

Comment: If we took the condition of being real analytic out of (1), then the converse would even be true.

Comment: But I want the result for one $w$. The result holds true for all $w∈ℝ$.

Comment: @AR1: What do you mean you want the result for one $w$?  You didn't ask about anything involving one $w$. You asked for the converse of the result you stated.

Comment: I mean the logical inverse of the result.

Comment: @ Jonas Meyer: How we can prove that converse is true.

Comment: @AR1 What Jonas Meyer said. If you want $(3') \implies ((1)\land (2))$ with $$(3') \text{ the fiber }g^{-1}(w) \text{ is infinite for some } w\in \Bbb R,$$ then that's a completly different question.

Comment: @AR1: You can't prove it is true unless you remove the condition of real analyticity from (1). In that case you don't even need continuity to show that (3) implies (1) and (2).  I am not going to write a proof; you could ask about what you got stuck on.